# Scanning a range of ports with Ncat?

Tags: networking, nmap, netcat, port-scanning

I'm aware that **Nmap** is the obvious choice for this task, however I would still like to know if it's possible to scan a range of ports with Ncat.

I see that I'm able to scan **one** port, but with a range of ports I get an error.

With **traditional Netcat** I see that it works, but with **Ncat**, when I run:

```
ncat -vzw1 scanme.nmap.org 20-25
```

I get:

```
Ncat: Version 7.91 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Invalid port number "20-25". QUITTING.
```

Answer (score 0):

That default Ncat is from Nmap, so that range of ports don't work for some reason.

You can then run : `/bin/nc.traditional -nv IP 20-25`